# Determine the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^n+n}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^n+n}{n!}$

Using ratio test :

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(4^{n+1}+n+1)n!}{(n+1)!(4^n+n)}\\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(4^{n+1}+n+1)}{(n+1)(4^n+n)}$

I think it's converges, but I didn't know how to solve the limit.

Comment: Split ot into two series.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, clearly $\sum \frac{4^n}{n!}$ converges (to $e^4$, in fact). Now, similarly, one can use the ratio test or just notice that

$$ \sum \frac{n}{n!} = \sum \frac{1}{(n-1)!} = ... $$

Answer (score 0):

The function $\mathrm{e}^x=\sum_{n=0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ is finite for $x=4$ as well as for any other real such as $x=5$.

My approach is to show that your sum (with the $4^n+n$ in the nominator of each term) is dominated $\sum_{n=0}\frac{5^n}{n!}$, i.e. the number $\mathrm{e}^5=148.413..$.

So what needs to be shown is just that $4^n+n\le 5^n$.

Note: I start at $n=0$ here for convenience (as the exponential is defined that was), but the first term is clearly the same (namely equal to $1$) for both series and so I could also just drop it as well.

---

Firstly, the condition can also written as $4^n\le 5^n-n$.

For $n=0$ we have that

$4^0 = 5^0 - 0$

and actually also

$4^1 = 5^1 - 1$.

Now, by induction,

$4^{(n+1)} = 4^n\cdot 4\le (5^n-n) \cdot (5-1) = 5^{n+1} -  (4\,n + 5^n) \le 5^{n+1}-(n+1).$

and we're done.

Note: We could even use weaker language: In principle we merely need to show that the sum is smaller than some constant, so we wouldn't have to start at $n=0$ but merely prove $4^n\le 5^n-n$ for some sufficiently large $n$ onwards. That it holds for all $n$ is a simplification of the initial condition, $4^0 = 5^0 - 0$.